# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a couple of questions in regards to dates in SQL Server.

1. How do I separate a `datetime` value "2011-08-10 14:56:17.267" into date and timestamp in two separate columns. Eg. Date "2011-08-10" and timestamp "14:56:17"
2. I want remove the timestamp from `datetime` value into "2011-08-10" and still be able to order the data by date (therefore not converted to `varchar`). Also is there away to change the date value as '10 Aug 2011' and still can sort (not alphabetically but in real date order).

Thank you,
HL

Comment: These two questions should probably be posted separately.

Answer (score 6):

For the first one:

```
UPDATE atable
SET
  DateColumn = CAST(DateTimeColumn AS date),
  TimeColumn = CAST(DateTimeColumn AS time)
```

As for the second one, date display format is something that is unrelated to the date *value*. You can order the result set by your date column, but in the SELECT clause you can use CONVERT to display the date in the desired format. For example:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar, DateColumn, 106) AS Date,
  …
FROM atable
ORDER BY DateColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

use CONVERT function with parameters from resource http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145

```
-- simple conversion example:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) -- for date
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 8)  -- for time
```